# Adding part of HTML to file using PHP

Tags: php, html, file

I trying to add HTML line in "userlist.php" using PHP code:

```
<?php
  $username = "pajlok";
  $type =  ".jpg";
  $html = <<<EOD
<div onclick="window.location.href = 'user/pajlok/'" style="background: url('user/pajlok/img/"

EOD;
  $html2 = <<<EOD
  ') !important" class="thumb"></div>

EOD;

  file_put_contents("../userslist.php", $html, $username, $type, $html2, FILE_APPEND . '\n\n');
?>
```

but I taking error message:

**Warning: file_put_contents() expects at most 4 parameters, 6 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\rs new\admin\addtolist.php on line 20**

and I don't know what's wrong with this code and don't know how to fix that

Comment: use `\') !important" class="thumb"></div>`

Comment: [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) expects 4 parameters, but you provided 6!. First parameter is file name, second is the data you want to insert into the file, third are flags e.g. FILE_APPEND.

Comment: Okay but I want to add this DIV. So, which parameter can I delete?

Comment: You also have a parse error. Enable error reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, file_put_contents() takes up to 4 parameters. Since you specified 6, there are some that need to be merged/omitted. Since I understood that what you want is to include the DIV in the PHP file, the HTML code was included in one variable, along with the $username and $type variables.
The line feed (PHP symbol for new line, /n) was placed at the end of the HTML code. As recommended, error reporting was added.

```
 <?php
  //ERRORS DISPLAY
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

  $username = "pajlok";
  $type =  ".jpg";
  $html = <<<EOD
    <div onclick="window.location.href = 'user/pajlok/'" style="background: url('user/pajlok/img/$username$type') !important" class="thumb"></div>\n
EOD;

  file_put_contents("../userslist.php", $html, FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

Comment: Just saying "Try this" can be taken as this analogy: Say somebody told you to "try this" little yellow or blue pill, what would you tell that person? Personally, I'd ask them why I should try/take that pill, asking them also what it is and what does it do. Surely there must be a reason why someone should try that pill. Think about that for a minute.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If that's what the downvote is for, I'll correct it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Well, we know you weren't born in 49... otherwise you would have been trying all sorts of little pills....

Comment: This seems to make sense. I would change a couple things.... `.href='user/$username'` and `url('user/$username/img...` to ensure that it would create a correct `<div>` during each iteration of the script.

Comment: @elbrant ROLMHO!!!!! True that. Mind you, "Mother's little helper" always came through with flying colors ;-)